# Inverse images of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $f\colon R\to S$ be a ring epimorphism, $I \subseteq S$ be an ideal, and $J = f^{-1}(I)$. Check that if $I$ is maximal (resp. prime) then $J$ is also maximal (resp. prime).

I had no trouble with the prime part, but I'm having a bit of trouble checking the maximal part. I think I am close, though.

Let $J \subseteq J' \subseteq R$ be another ideal. Then $f(J) \subseteq f(J') \subseteq f(R)$. Since $f$ is an epimorphism, this actually reads $I \subseteq f(J') \subseteq S$, with $f(J')$ being an ideal (again using surjectivity). Since $I$ is maximal, we have that $f(J')$ is either $I$ or $S$.

If $f(J')= I$, then $x \in J' \implies f(x) \in f(J') = I \implies x \in f^{-1}(I) = J$, and $J' = J$.

If $f(J') = S$, then $x \in R \implies f(x) \in S = f(J') \implies x \in f^{-1}(f(J))$, but I can't conclude that $x \in J$ from here ($f$ need not be injective).

Help?

---

We do **not** assume that rings are commutative and have $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editted to remove reference to unity**

Continuing along the lines of your solution, we want to show that every $y \in R$ is also in $J'$. Note in particular, since the assumption is that $f(J')=S$, that there exists $x \in J'$ so that $f(x) = f(y)$. But then $$f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)=0,$$ so $$x-y \in J = f^{-1}(I).$$ Can you see what to do from here?

Comment: More or less. We should *start* with an arbitrary $x \in J'$, not get the existence of one, in what I understand... but the real problem is that we don't assume that rings have $1$ here, I should have said that in the answer (I'll do it now and I apologize for that).

Comment: @IvoTerek That doesn't make it much more difficult; the use of unity just allows one to abbreviate what it means to have $J'=R$. Editted accordingly.

Comment: That was more clear. I could finish it here, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $R/J\cong S/I$, hence if one is a domain or field so is the other.